# How to create a random unice Id mongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

for my final project, I'm doing a simple Manager app for Car repairment Garages, for DB I'm using MongoDB and I saw a great tutorial by Tim corny, but I don't know how to generate an Unice Id for each object.

this is my class Actions for each object in the Database

```
public class MongoActions
    {
        private static Random random;
        public static void UpsertRecord<T>(int id, string table, T record)
        {
            var collection =  Mongo.db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            var result = collection.ReplaceOne(
                new BsonDocument("_id", id),
                record,
                new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true }
                );
        }
        public static int RandomId<T>(string table)
        {
            **//how to find a nice Id that is not repeated** 


        }   

        public static void  InsertRecord<T>(string table, T record)
        {
            var collection = Mongo.db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            collection.InsertOne(record);
        }
        public static T FindRecord<T>(string table, string field, string value)
        {
            var collection = Mongo.db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            var fillter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(field, value);
            return collection.Find(fillter).First();

        }
        public static List<T> FillterRecords<T>(string table, string field, string value)
        {
            var collection = Mongo.db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            var fillter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(field, value);
            return collection.Find(fillter).ToList();
        }
        public static List<T> LoadRecords<T>(string table)
        {
            var collection = Mongo.db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            return collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
        }
        public static void DeleteRecord<T>(string table,int id)
        {
            var collection = Mongo.db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            var fillter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
            collection.DeleteOne(fillter);
        }
    }
```

and this is the connection class

```
public static class Mongo
    {
        public static string database = "Garage";
        public static MongoClient client=new MongoClient();
        public static IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase(database);
    }
```

I will be glad if someone help me

Comment: Do you mean a unique id?

Comment: yes, sorry my English is a little bad

Comment: Don't use int as the data type. Rather use Guid which is a globally unique value.
`Guid.NewGuid()`

Comment: Is there an Id field on the class of the object you're saving? For upserts/inserts, the Mongo driver will generate `ObjectId` ids if you've got it set up correctly. Out of the box it will use any `ObjectId` property decorated with `[BsonId]` for this purpose.

Comment: yes, for each table I'm using a prop with a name Id, and then above the prop there is a [BsonId]

Comment: for example, I have a table "shift" with properties {id, start, end, worker}
and for every new shift, I want to generate a new random id.
and I'm not familiar with MongoDB as an expart

Comment: Non of the above code is needed. Just use `db` as is. It's already generic.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Id to be an `ObjectId` and don't set it before an insert, this way the database engine will set it on your behave and set it on your object:

Checkout the following code:

```cs
class Order
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Order>("orders");

// Leave the Id on Order as `null`
var myOrder = new Order {Name = "My Order"};
// Once we insert the Order the Id will be set.
await collection.InsertOneAsync(myOrder);

Console.WriteLine($"Order Id: {myOrder.Id}"); // Order Id: 5edbb15c75e67361d07362c2
Console.WriteLine($"Order Id: {myOrder.Name}"); // Order Id: My Order
```